# Jenkins to Nexus Copying

Tags: jenkins, integration, nexus

We have a Git/Gradle project wherein WAR file is created. Already created a task in Jenkins to build and create a WAR file.

I would like to copy this file and host it on Nexus.

Checked there's not post build task in my Jenkins which will automatically copy that file to Nexus.

However I see an option to launch a Nexus task.

Read that we have to create some plugins/

As I am an end user of Jenkins/Nexus is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would just use Maven, Ant or Gradle to build and deploy the war to Nexus. Any reason you are not doing that?